# DLNA/UPNP / TWONKY / WIFI issue

Tags: wifi-configuration, dlna, upnp

I have an adsl modem/router (192.168.1.1) which has two devices attached:

- a NAS Lacie Networkstorage 2 with Twonky DLNA/IPNP media server on board
- a Netgear WNR2000 wifi router (172.16.0.1)

both routers serve DHCP on their respective subnetworks.

While the media server operates correctly with any client (djmount is fantastic!) attached to 192.168.1.1, it is not visible when the pc is connected through wifi.

I've disabled UPnP support on the netgear router with no luck.

Which configuration should I try?